# Best way to audit dependencies in Yarn 2 (berry)?

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, npm-audit, yarnpkg-v2

I'm looking for a way to audit dependencies for vulnerabilities in Yarn 2. In Yarn 1.x it was possible the same was as in `npm`, by running `yarn audit` instead of `npm audit`. But with Yarn 2 there is no such command. And according to [this issue](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/1187) on the berry github, it won't be implemented (project maintainers prefer it was done via plugin).

I have tried running `npm install --package-lock-only && npm audit` but the install chokes on some of my local packages (which I am listing in package.json using the `link:` url type).

It wouldn't be a complex plugin to build and I'm up for some fun doing so, but it would not be so muchfun as just installing something and then going about my day. I have looked around but always end up at the same couple of vapourware / abandonware repos.

But I still guess that I'm just not finding them. Or there's an undocumented trick for making it easy. Hence my question :)

PS, yeah I can delete the local packages using `link:` temporarily while I run the `npm install` and `npm audit` commands above, but it's not exactly the kind of thing I want to try and automate for CI.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update (28-Oct-2020):**
Yarn 2 just merged long-awaited `yarn npm audit` enhancement.

PR - https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/pull/1892
Docs - https://yarnpkg.com/cli/npm/audit

---

I was experimenting with Yarn 2 recently, and I saw that you can do this with [@efrem/auditdeps](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@efrem/auditdeps) utility:

```
yarn dlx @efrem/auditdeps [--level=(low|moderate|high|critical)] [--production]
```

The output is not as pretty as from `npm audit`, but you get more details in JSON format and you can pipe it to other tools or to any custom reformatting script to get exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried using this but it is one of the ones I mentioned as being a bit vapourish :) no issues, one star, one contributor.

When using it I receive ERROR: Expected "@", [^/@], or end of input but "/" found (line 1, column 18).

Comment: Thanks for the update! Sorry I didn't see this until now :)

Answer (score -2):

I'd try https://snyk.io/ not free for huge team commercial use, but it could get you started on daily runs etc.

( I'm not affiliated in any way with Snyk.io )

Comment: It does look nice but WOW does it get pricey once you hit 10 devs.